# Проблема с typeOf()

Tags: javascript

вот мой код

```
const someString = 'This is some strange string';

function reverse(str) {
    if(typeof(str) == String) {
        let arr = str.split('',str.lenght);
        let rev = arr.reverse();
        let fin = `${rev.join('')}`;
        return fin;
    } else {
        
        return 'erorr';
        
    }
}




// в этой задаче нюанс с неравно строке


console.log(reverse(someString));
```

Функция для создания реверсивной строки. Если в аргумент будет дана не строка , то должна вернуться ошибка. Я использую тайп оф и почему то получается наоборот. Пишу `typeof(str) !== String` и выводится код в иф.

Если же убираю `!==` и ставлю `==` то выводится блок `else (erorr)`.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно будет

```
typeof(str) == 'string' // можно даже ===
```

т.к. оператор `typeof` возвращает **строку**, указывающую тип операнда. А `String` это в данном контексте просто какая-то константа. А, точнее, это имя функции